# Update Table/T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 5 columns.
I want to update 5th column (NULL by default)  based on values in columns 1 to 4. If 1st column is null, Add "c1" to 5th column If 2nd column is null, add "c2" to the 5th column and so on.
Also, if 1st and 2nd columns are null, I want to add "C1, C2" to 5th column and so on.
How can I achieve that.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET C5 = 
Case 
 when C1 IS NULL then 'C!' 
 WHEN C2 IS NULL then 'C2' 
 WHEN C3 IS NULL THEN 'C3' 
 WHEN C4 IS NULL ThEN 'C4' 
END
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: UPDATE TABLE SET C5 = Case when C1 IS NULL then 'C!' WHEN C2 IS NULL then 'C2' WHEN C3 IS NULL THEN 'C3' WHEN C4 IS NULL ThEN 'C4' END

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu because he posted it on a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this:

```
UPDATE table
SET C5 = ISNULL(REPLACE(C1,C1,''),',C1')
          +ISNULL(REPLACE(C2,C2,''),',C2')
          +ISNULL(REPLACE(C3,C3,''),',C3')
          +ISNULL(REPLACE(C4,C4,''),',C4')
```

etc.

The idea is that you use `REPLACE` to leave you with blank '' or `NULL`, then use `ISNULL` to add the field name if `NULL`.

You could craft the query in Excel pretty quickly, it will leave one errant comma at the end of the string, if that's a problem it can be easily dealt with:

```
UPDATE table
SET C5 = STUFF(ISNULL(REPLACE(C1,C1,''),',C1 ')
                  +ISNULL(REPLACE(C2,C2,''),',C2 ')
                  +ISNULL(REPLACE(C3,C3,''),',C3 ')
                  +ISNULL(REPLACE(C4,C4,''),',C4 '),1,2,'')
```

Update:  Changed to using STUFF() function instead of LEFT() to eliminate errant comma, and added a space between listed items.

Comment: More practical solution to extra comma is to prepend comma to column name (like ',C1') and later use [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) to remove first one: `stuff(expr, 1, 1, '')`

Comment: This works like a charm with Replace function to add space after middle commas. :)

Comment: I am getting "Error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." Do you know why?

Comment: Yeah, you've got instances where none of the fields are populated, so it's asking for the LEFT -1 of it, see updated answer using STUFF() function, also you don't need to add a space with REPLACE, you could just add it to the `',C1'` portion like `',C1 '`

Comment: See updated answer, and to clarify, I meant situations where none of the fields were NULL were causing -1 to be passed to the LEFT function, STUFF will just return NULL in those instances, so you may want to wrap it all in another ISNULL to return ''.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tbl
SET fifth = CASE
    WHEN first IS NULL AND second IS NULL and third IS NULL and fourth IS NULL THEN "C1, C2, C3, C4"
    WHEN .... -- all 15 cases
```

Comment: Thanks but is there another (shorter) way? I have MANY columns (I just said 5 as an example).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but something like this should work:

```
update table1 set c5 =
(case when c1 is null then 'C1,' else '' end ||      
 case when c2 is null then 'C2,' else '' end || 
 case when c3 is null then 'C3,' else '' end || 
 case when c4 is null then 'C4' else '' end)
```

I leave the exercise of trimming the trailing comma, if needed, to someone better at t-sql string manipulation.

Comment: having some trouble understanding the OR part. Is || taking care of multiple columns with NUlls > Multiple values into 5th column?

Comment: @user1569220 `||` is concatenation in Oracle. For Sql Server use '+'.

Comment: it's shorthand for concatenate - come to think of it, t-sql might not support it?

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks! I will try this. Below this I will write another update statement which basically says, IF C5 like '%,' THEN RTRIM 1 char else nothing or something like that. Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t SET C5 = 
REPLACE(REPLACE(
  CASE C1 WHEN NULL THEN 'C1' ELSE '' END+'<>'+
  CASE C2 WHEN NULL THEN 'C2' ELSE '' END+'<>'+
  CASE C3 WHEN NULL THEN 'C3' ELSE '' END+'<>'+
  CASE C4 WHEN NULL THEN 'C4' ELSE '' END,
'><',''),'<>',',')
```